# Create folders from an Excel table

Tags: excel, directory, import-from-excel

I am new here. I'm trying to create different folders with different names from an Excel file(table with row and columns) in a specific path. Below my coding.

```
import openpyxl
import os

w = openpyxl.load_workbook("test1.xlsx")                       

worksheet = w.active


for i in range(1 , worksheet.max_row):                                                                  
    for j in worksheet.iter_cols(1,worksheet.max_column):                                               
        end =  "D:\\Roberto"                                                                            
        os.makedirs ((j[i].value), end == "\t\t" )
    os.makedirs( (j[i]) , (" ") )
```

To thom is going to ask: I don't know why Pandas is not working on my system, so I'm using this as source:

```
import openpyxl   
w = openpyxl.load_workbook("test1.xlsx")
worksheet = w.active
for i in range(0 , worksheet.max_row):
    for j in worksheet.iter_cols(1,worksheet.max_column):
        print(j[i].value, end = "\t\t")
    print(" ")
```

Thanks!

The program is not working properly, because it's doing folders only for the cells of the first line. Moreover, it's saving in the same directory where the *.py file is located, not in the path that I want.

Comment: " it's saving in the same directory where the *.py file is located"  -->> u can run the *py ON the path that u want.. That should do.. right?

Comment: Yes, but if I want to give the path of another destination, what should I write?

I have modified line 4 in:

w = openpyxl.load_workbook(input("Please insert the name of the excel file: " ))  , then I insert the name of the file, filename.xslx, but it gives me the mistake

openpyxl.utils.exceptions.InvalidFileException: openpyxl does not support .xslx file format, please check you can open it with Excel first. Supported formats are: .xlsx,.xlsm,.xltx,.xltm